# Desactivar pop-up de confirmación del iframe cuando en el src tiene https

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

Mi pagina es la siguiente cuando le doy en CONTINUAR me sale el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Deseo desactivar ese `pop-up` de confirmación.

Mi desarrollo está en `jquery` usando `iframe` con web `responsive` en el `src` del `iframe` le envió la siguiente ruta.

https://www.mipagina.com.pe/SOA/Pago?pro=2629&ide=19855844&moneda=SOL&monto=89&viapago=VIS

El desarrollo es el siguiente.

```
 function cargarUrl(){
    iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
    var ideacuerdo = $("#ideacuerdo").val();
    var moneda = $("#moneda").val();
    var producto = $("#producto").val();
    var monto = $("#monto").val();
    var url = '../SOA/pago?producto='+pro+'&ide='+ideacuerdo+'&moneda='+moneda+'&monto='+monto;
    if(viapago == 'VIS'){
        iframe.width = '100%';
        iframe.height = '538px';
    }else{
        iframe.width = '760px';
        iframe.height = '600px';
    }
    iframe.src = url;
    closeAlert();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer alguno de tus script esta utilizando el evento onbeforeunload, al no tener acceso al ejemplo completo no se si este evento esta asignado a la pagina o al iframe. Intenta agregar las siguientes lineas de codigo justo antes de cambiar el src del iframe.

```
iframe.onbeforeunload = null;
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Con esto lo que hacemos es desasociar el evento onbeforeunload tanto de la ventana como del iframe.