# Bloquear popup de confirmación del iframe cuando en el src tiene https

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi pagina es la siguiente cuando le doy en CONTINUAR me sale el siguiente mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Deseo desactivar ese popUp de confirmación.

Mi desarrollo esta en jquery usando iframe con web responsive en el src del iframe le envió la siguiente ruta.

https://www.mipagina.com.pe/SOA/Pago?pro=2629&ide=19855844&moneda=SOL&monto=89&viapago=VIS

El desarrollo es el siguiente.

```html
<div id="mostrarForma" style=" text-align: center; height: 600px;">
<iframe id="frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" scrollbar="no" ></iframe>
</div>
```

```js
function cargarUrl(){
        iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
        var ide = $("#ide").val();
        var moneda = $("#moneda").val();
        var pro = $("#pro").val();
        var monto = $("#monto").val();
        var url = '../SOA/pago?pro='+pro+'&ide='+ide+'&moneda='+moneda+'&monto='+monto;
        if(viapago == 'VIS'){
            iframe.width = '100%';
            iframe.height = '538px';
        }else{
            iframe.width = '760px';
            iframe.height = '600px';
        }
        iframe.src = url;
        closeAlert();

    };
```

Comment: No hay necesidad de repetir la pregunta. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15864/desactivar-popup-de-confirmaci%C3%B3n-del-iframe-cuando-en-el-src-tiene-https